# Create snytax highlighter using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a snytax highlighter.
Especially for **SQL**.

I got a solution in the internet but it was not working.

**index.js**

```
var codeElements = $(".article pre code");
var strReg1 = /"(.*?)"/g,
    strReg2 = /'(.*?)'/g,
    specialReg = /\b(new|var|if|do|function|while|switch|for|foreach|in|continue|break)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialJsGlobReg = /\b(document|window|Array|String|Object|Number|\$)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialJsReg = /\b(getElementsBy(TagName|ClassName|Name)|getElementById|typeof|instanceof)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialMethReg = /\b(indexOf|match|replace|toString|length)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialPhpReg  = /\b(define|echo|print_r|var_dump)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialCommentReg  = /(\/\*.*\*\/)/g,
    inlineCommentReg = /(\/\/.*)/g;

var htmlTagReg = /(&lt;[^\&]*&gt;)/g;

var sqlReg = /\b(CREATE|ALL|DATABASE|TABLE|GRANT|PRIVILEGES|IDENTIFIED|FLUSH|SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|FROM|WHERE|ORDER|BY|GROUP|LIMIT|INNER|OUTER|AS|ON|COUNT|CASE|TO|IF|WHEN|BETWEEN|AND|OR)(?=[^\w])/g;

codeElements.each(function (){
    var string = this.innerHTML,
    parsed = string.replace(strReg1,'<span class="string">"$1"</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(strReg2,"<span class=\"string\">'$1'</span>");
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialReg,'<span class="special">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialJsGlobReg,'<span class="special-js-glob">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialJsReg,'<span class="special-js">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialMethReg,'<span class="special-js-meth">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(htmlTagReg,'<span class="special-html">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(sqlReg,'<span class="special-sql">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialPhpReg,'<span class="special-php">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialCommentReg,'<span class="special-comment">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(inlineCommentReg,'<span class="special-comment">$1</span>');

    this.innerHTML = parsed;
});
```

**index.css**

```
pre code .string {
    color:#A1E46D;
}
pre code .special {
    color:#D6665D;
}
pre code .special-js {
    color:#6DE4D1;
}
pre code .special-js-glob {
    color:#A1E46D;
    font-weight:bold;
}
pre code .special-comment{
    color:#aaa;
}
pre code .special-js-meth {
    color:#E46D8A;
}
pre code .special-html {
    color:#E4D95F;
}
pre code .special-sql {
    color:#1D968C;
}
pre code .special-php{
    color:#597EA7;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <title>highlightme Test Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <pre>
        <code>
            var test = "Test";
        </code>
     </pre>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have used **jQuery**.
If there's any error please help me.

And I am actually creating my own snytax highlighter so please don't suggest me bout js libraries.

Thank You

Comment: whats the question here? are you asking us to test your code?

Comment: *If there's any error please help me* ... well, you have to tell US if there is an error ... and WHAT the error actually IS - `I have used jQuery` never mind

Comment: You don't have any elements in your `index.html` that match the CSS selector `.article pre code`

Comment: You did not need jQuery for this at all.  This line: `codeElements = $(".article pre code")` could have been replaced by `document.querySelectorAll(".article pre code")` and `codeElements.each` replaced by `Array.from(codeElements).forEach`

Comment: @Tibrogargan - `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` ... a `NodeList` has it's own `.forEach` ... so, no need for `Array.from`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any elements in your index.html that match the CSS selector `.article pre code`

```js
var codeElements = $(".article pre code");
var strReg1 = /"(.*?)"/g,
    strReg2 = /'(.*?)'/g,
    specialReg = /\b(new|var|if|do|function|while|switch|for|foreach|in|continue|break)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialJsGlobReg = /\b(document|window|Array|String|Object|Number|\$)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialJsReg = /\b(getElementsBy(TagName|ClassName|Name)|getElementById|typeof|instanceof)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialMethReg = /\b(indexOf|match|replace|toString|length)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialPhpReg  = /\b(define|echo|print_r|var_dump)(?=[^\w])/g,
    specialCommentReg  = /(\/\*.*\*\/)/g,
    inlineCommentReg = /(\/\/.*)/g;

var htmlTagReg = /(&lt;[^\&]*&gt;)/g;

var sqlReg = /\b(CREATE|ALL|DATABASE|TABLE|GRANT|PRIVILEGES|IDENTIFIED|FLUSH|SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|FROM|WHERE|ORDER|BY|GROUP|LIMIT|INNER|OUTER|AS|ON|COUNT|CASE|TO|IF|WHEN|BETWEEN|AND|OR)(?=[^\w])/g;

codeElements.each(function (){
    var string = this.innerHTML,
    parsed = string.replace(strReg1,'<span class="string">"$1"</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(strReg2,"<span class=\"string\">'$1'</span>");
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialReg,'<span class="special">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialJsGlobReg,'<span class="special-js-glob">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialJsReg,'<span class="special-js">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialMethReg,'<span class="special-js-meth">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(htmlTagReg,'<span class="special-html">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(sqlReg,'<span class="special-sql">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialPhpReg,'<span class="special-php">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(specialCommentReg,'<span class="special-comment">$1</span>');
    parsed = parsed.replace(inlineCommentReg,'<span class="special-comment">$1</span>');

    this.innerHTML = parsed;
});
```

```css
pre code .string {
    color:#A1E46D;
}
pre code .special {
    color:#D6665D;
}
pre code .special-js {
    color:#6DE4D1;
}
pre code .special-js-glob {
    color:#A1E46D;
    font-weight:bold;
}
pre code .special-comment{
    color:#aaa;
}
pre code .special-js-meth {
    color:#E46D8A;
}
pre code .special-html {
    color:#E4D95F;
}
pre code .special-sql {
    color:#1D968C;
}
pre code .special-php{
    color:#597EA7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="article">
     <pre>
        <code>
            var test = "Test";
        </code>
     </pre>
 </body>
```